# Pros and Cons of Vectors in Illustrator vs sketches in Autodesk Sketchbook Pro for Website Use

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, autodesk-sketchbook-pro

My website is going to include a lot of graphics, drawn by myself. The display of the illustrations will be similar to that of theoatmeal.com (some illustration reuse will be present, but not as much as in most comics and the drawings will not be in boxes but simply appropriately placed on the page).

I'm having a hard time deciding between the resizability of vector vs. the intricacies and ease of Sketchbook drawings.

The way I see it, at the end of the day, my final graphic is going to lose quality when it's resized in a browser no matter what. However, this may make development a little bit harder.

For one, I lose the ability to re-use a lot of graphics and make minor changes to them. But I already have my main canvas laid out in illustrator, so I know in relation to that, the size that my drawings should be - this should result in little need to resize.

Ideally, if I could draw the skeleton of my illustrations in vector, then add detail(like shading) in Sketchbook, that is what I would most prefer. Does anyone know any limitations to this? For those with experience, what do you do/suggest?

Comment: In the end, unless you're using SVG, everything on the web is raster. What you use prior to getting that final raster image is of little importance.